# Three20, different images for portrait and landscape orientation possible?

Tags: image, orientation, three20, swap, uiinterfaceorientation

I am using three20 to present a photo essay of a story I made after the February earthquake in Chile. I would like the app to display portrait type images when iPad device is in portrait orientation and landscape type images when iPad device is in landscape orientation.
So there would be two versions of every image, one cropped for portrait viewing and one cropped for landscape viewing and the app would show the version that is appropriate for the orientation the device is in.

I will crop these image versions separately. That way, the app would make full use of the screen in all orientations and users will read the story like a magazine.
Ideally, the view would change over to the corresponding image, staying where it is in the sequence of images, when the user rotates the device, so from portrait #4 to landscape #4 and vice versa, for example. But, if this is not possible, jumping back to the first image whenever iPad device is rotated is acceptable as well (push to separate TTImageViews maybe?)

The idea is to give to user the experience he is reading an illustrated story in all orientations. Can this be done? If so, can you give some clues?

If it can not be done putting a specific image in the background with the image viewer overlaying it may also be a solution. If separate fullscreen views for each orientation are not possible, then at least I would like to get rid of the black "autoresizing mask" parts of the screen..

Many thanks!
diederik